# Display user profile url by name instead of ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, backend

I am Newbie. I'm trying to return a view of member profile

At the moment, the user profile is accessible by its **ID**, like so

> profile/7

I would like to access it through the **name** that I've created

> profile/John

this is my route

```
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'ProfilController@tampilkanID');
```

this is my controller

```
public function tampilkanID($id)
{
    $auth = Auth::user()->id;
    $users=\App\users::all()->whereNotIn('id',$auth);
    $tampilkan = Users::find($id);
    return view('tampilkan', compact('tampilkan', 'users')); 
}
```

and this how i call it in my blade

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
           <tr>
               <td><a id="teamname" href="{{ url('profile',$user->id) }}" target="_blank">{{$user->name}}</a></td>
              </tr>
 @endforeach
```

thank you

Comment: ,$user->id
just change the id with your database user name

Comment: there is possibility for multiple entries with same name, how will you find unique entry from name??

Comment: Take out the error suppression, think how you can append the user to the url by keeping the id in storage somewhere. You will not be able to validate solely on the name alone if there are multiple enteries with the same name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

Route:

```
Route::any('profile/{name}', 'ProfilController@index')->name('profile.index');
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request, $name)
{
    $user = User::where('name', $name)->first();
    if(isset($user))
        return view('tampilkan', ['user' => $user]);
    return "user not found!"; 
}
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td><a id="teamname" href="{{ route('profile.index',['name' => $user->name]) }}" target="_blank">{{$user->name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

**Suggestion:**
if you're doing this, you should also set "name" column to "unique" in `users` table in order to get exactly one user each time and not confuse users to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel `Route Model Binding`.

**What is Route Model Binging?**

Route model binding in Laravel provides a mechanism to inject a model instance into your routes.

**How can I use it?**

Pass `object rather then id` like

```
Route::get('users/{user}', function ($user) {
    return view('user.show', compact('user'));
});
```

In your `User.php` define `getRouteKeyName` then return whatever you want as a route

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name'; //this will return user name as route 
}
```

so your route will be `users/name`

For more information have a look at laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

Just Customise you RouteServiceProvider as Like below :

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return App\User::where('name', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```

or

customise your route key in model.

For eg :

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

Route :

```
Route::get('users/{user}', function ($user) {
    return view('user.show', compact('user'));
});
```