# How to find user by user name in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to find user by user name while building a laravel API. This is what I'm trying

**api.php**

```
Route::get('user-profile/user/{user}', 'UserProfileController@getUserProfile');
```

**Controller**

```
public function getUserProfile(User $user)
{
    $userId = User::where('userName', $user->userName)->first()->id; // I am expecting user id here like "1"
}
```

This causing 404 not found error.

Comment: If your User table primary key is `id`, and the URL you are using looks like `user-profile/user/1` for eg, where `1` is the ID, then you are using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding), and Laravel has already found the `$user` for you.  In your controller, just `$user->id` will give you the ID.

Comment: Note though that the controller method you've shown us is not the one the route you've shown us calls.  I guess you are getting a 404 because `getUserProfile` != `getUserPortfolio`.

Comment: If you are trying to look up user by name, not id, there are plenty of duplicates here on SO, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626792/display-user-profile-url-by-name-instead-of-id

Comment: my url looks like `user-profile/user/dontPanic21` which means I am trying to search user by their username not  by their id. In that case should I modify the route to `Route::get('user-portfolio/users/{user:userName}'`  as the doc suggesting https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding ?

the route and controller function are ok. i fixed that typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default route model binding search for `id` and in your case you want search by `username` so all you need is to remove dependency injection from your controller parameters like this

```php
public function getUserPortfolio($user) // fix it as $user only
{
    $userId = User::where('userName', $user)->first()->id; // I am expecting user id here like "1"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default route model binding will search for `id`.
You should customise the column name in your route if you want Laravel to select the user using the column `userName`.

In you **api.php**:

```
Route::get('user-profile/user/{user:userName}', 'UserProfileController@getUserProfile');
```

Assuming that your `userName` is unique in the table, then in your controller you should use:

```
public function getUserProfile(User $user)
{
    $userId = $user->id;
    ...
}
```

This will automatically handle 404 errors for you as opposed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950406/4356884) answer.